# p2os serial connection error

Tags: ros, serial, usb, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect to a Amigobot (similar to Pioneer) using the p2os stack. I am using an USB to Serial Converter in Ubuntu 10.11. I used rosparam set p2os/port /dev/ttyUSB0 to set the port to USB0. Unfortunatetly when I try to connect I get this error:

```
roslaunch p2os_launch p2os_driver.launch
... logging to /home/mario/.ros/log/cdf4ba1a-0bb0-11e2-8b6f-37e053dcb6c9/roslaunch-mario-Satellite-C660-12071.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://mario-Satellite-C660:56326/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosversion
 * /rosdistro

NODES
  /
    p2os (p2os_driver/p2os)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[p2os-1]: started with pid [12089]
[ERROR] [1349087058.764888277]: Error reading packet header from robot connection: P2OSPacket():Receive():read():
.
.
.
[ERROR] [1349087114.446749752]: Error reading packet header from robot connection: P2OSPacket():Receive():read():
[ERROR] [1349087114.447846009]: p2os setup failed...
[p2os-1] process has died [pid 12089, exit code 255].
log files: /home/mario/.ros/log/cdf4ba1a-0bb0-11e2-8b6f-37e053dcb6c9/p2os-1*.log
```

The output of the log file looks like this

```
^[[0m[ INFO] [1349093885.560391832]: using serial port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]^[[0m
^[[0m[ INFO] [1349093885.637932732]: P2OS connection opening serial port /dev/ttyUSB0...^[[0m
```

Maybe the baud rate is not correct? Do I have to set it manually?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44845/p2os-serial-connection-error/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-10-01**:
Mario, I suspect that this is the same problem that we're trying to debug in this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/43375/p2os-connection/ Would you mind if I closed this as a duplicate so that we can combine efforts in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can close this post. Besides I was using a wrong port...

---

Originally posted by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) with karma: 82 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0